# TLS как функция для обработки массива байт

Tags: c, tls

Я ищу инструкцию или библиотеку, в которой будет реализованы в виде функций набор шагов по созданию шифрованного соединения по протоколу TSL. Все примеры, которые я смотрел просто сразу создают TLS-сервер поверх сокетов. Но мне бы хотелось найти такой способ, чтобы можно было пошагово выполнить

- Отправить запрос с версией
- Принять запрос с версий
- Выбрать алгоритм шифрования
- выполнить обмен ключами
- т.д.

Мне нужна реализация которая просто содержит набор функций на языке Си (не Си++) и позволяет обработать голые массивы байт, а не делает все внутри себя полностью подменяя TCP сервер без шифрования.

Для чего мне это нужно. У меня есть TCP сервер на WL и хочу подключить к нему шифрование, которого по умолчанию нет, но я хочу при этом чтобы TLS подключался как протокол поверх TCP, а не чтобы был просто монолитный сервер. Прошу прощения за легкий сумбур, всем заранее спасибо

Comment: Читай про openssl BIO

Comment: @eri спасибо большое

Comment: Выглядит так, будто вы хотите самостоятельно реализовать TLS. Конечно, это можно cсделать средствами openssl, но в целом это довольно спорное решение, имхо. Верный способ выстрелить себе в ногу. Внутри каждого шага куча тонкостей и опций, которые нужно уметь правильно обработать. Особенно меня порадовало ваше *и т.д.* - это как если на схеме вечного двигателя написать "термоядерный реактор не указан для простоты". Я бы предложил использовать таки монолитный OpenSSL поверх сокета, а все необходимые параметры задать через SSL context

Comment: @PakUula в целом да, вы правы. Это выглядит как попытка реализовать протокол. Я бы рад использовать готовую реализацию именно протокола, но везде в качестве примера я нахожу только реализации готового сервера. Просто у меня есть сервер работающий по TCP. Все что он умеет - принимать байты и отправлять. Я хочу как отдельную функцию для обработки массива байт указать TLS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем случае у меня есть перпендикулярное предложение, основанное на собственном опыте. Я им регулярно пользуюсь для TSL защиты легаси серверов.

Вместо переписывания сервера я ставлю перед ним SSL-прокси, которая берёт на себя все операции, связанные с TLS, а легаси сервер работает за спиной прокси с открытыми данными. Для прокси я использую nginx:

- защита HTTP трафика: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/
- защита произвольного TCP трафика: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-tcp-traffic-upstream/.

Оверхед небольшой, зато надёжно, конфигурируемо, логируемо, обновляемо.

И вообще, я с содроганием отношусь к тому, чтобы выставлять сервера в продашене в прямой доступ - тут вам и атаки на TLS, и DDoS, и потенциальные проблемы с хостингом приложения.

Поэтому в последнее время я стал делать так:

1. Приложение засунуть в докер, выставив только серверный порт
2. Весь трафик пропускать через nginx, который берёт на себя TLS, балансировку нагрузки, health check и maintenance mode.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы правы, это действительно надежное решение! Я в том числе его уже рассматривал. просто я решаю очень специфическую задачу. Моя цель - добавить поддержку базовых протоколов в язык Wolfram Language - я реализовал работу с сокетами на низком уровне, добавил TCP, HTTP, WebSocket и некоторые другие небольшие протоколы, но я начал читать спецификацию по TLS и понял что это будет ну очень громоздко. Я не пытаюсь изобрести велосипед. а просто хочу добавить максимально минималистичную поддержку протоколов по отдельности. Но увы не могу найти подходящий вариант для TLS. Спасибо! =)

Comment: соответственно добавление TLS откроет доступ к HTTPS, WSS, HTTP2

Comment: @KirillBelov  Имхо, стоит пойти по пути Python. У вас в языке есть соглашение о вызове Си функций? Если да, сделайте обёртку вокруг openssl. Это многократно надёжнее, чем делать свою реализацию.

Comment: именно это я и ищу, только с одним условием - чтобы был не готовый сервер, а только часть отвечающая за шифрование

Comment: да, соглашение по вызову Си-функций есть

Comment: @KirillBelov имхо, шифрование в TLS это сравнительно небольшая часть. Протокол сам по себе очень сложный. Посмотрите какие функции экспортирует модуль ssl в Python https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html и сделайте так же . Это проверенный временем минимально разумный набор API для TLS

Comment: спасибо, именно так и сделаю, вы мне очень помогли!